# Chart.js v3 Fade Animation in delay

Tags: javascript, animation, chart.js, fade

I'm trying to create a Chart with Chart.js. I Got everything to work as I want it to, only thing left is that the Animation always floats from the bottom up into position. I just want a Fade-In animation, but couldn't find anything on how to do this.

Is it even possible to do a Fade Animation in Chart.js? Here is my Code so far:
#code

EDIT:

I got v3 to work, but a function, I created for this Chart doesn't work properly now. I start the Chart Animation 1s after its scrolled in view. By that time the Line chart is hidden and only the bar charts appear. After another 1.5s the Line is supposed to fade in on its spot.
I used to do this by giving the Line hidden at first and after a delay unhide it and update the chart. Updating the Chart now resets the Bar animation too. In v2 it didn't do this. Is there a way to play the animations shortly after another?

Also due to the Update the Plugin Datalabels doesn't work anymore. Is there a alternative in v3?

Here is my Code again:

```
<div class="chartcontainer">
    <div class="chartcontainer--inner">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@3.0.0-beta/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-deferred"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
                #myChart {min-height: 540px}
            }
            .chartcontainer {max-width: 67.625rem; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; overflow: hidden;}
            @media screen and (max-width: 700px){
                .chartcontainer--inner {width: 50rem;}
                .chartcontainer {overflow: scroll;}

            }
        </style>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var inView = false;

            function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
            {
                var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

                var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
                var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

                return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop));
            }

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if (isScrolledIntoView('#myChart') && !inView) {
                    // if (inView) { return; }
                    inView = true;

               console.log('in View: '+ inView);
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){

                        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'bar',
                            data: {
                                labels: ['2018', '2019', '2020'],
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: ['a'],
                                    data: [7.1, 6.6, 6.6],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        '#05368b',
                                        '#05368b',
                                        '#05368b'
                                    ],
                                    order: 2
                                },{
                                    label: ['b'],
                                    data: [6.5, 6.4, 6.7],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        '#1792d7',
                                        '#1792d7',
                                        '#1792d7'
                                    ],
                                    order: 2
                                },{
                                    label: ['c'],
                                    data: [6.1, 5.8, 6.1],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        '#6c2475',
                                        '#6c2475',
                                        '#6c2475'
                                    ],
                                    order: 2
                                },{
                                    label: ['d'],
                                    data: [5.7, 5.8, 5.8],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        '#0d60b5',
                                        '#0d60b5',
                                        '#0d60b5'
                                    ],
                                    order: 2
                                },{
                                    label: ['e'],
                                    data: [4.3, 6.1, 6.3],
                                    type: 'line',
                                    lineTension: 0.4,
                                    borderColor: "#f48d3b",
                                    fill: false,
                                    pointBackgroundColor: function() {
                                        var color = "rgba(244, 141, 59, 1)";
                                        console.log(color);
                                        return color;
                                    },
                                    pointRadius: function(context) {
                                        var width = context.chart.width;
                                        var size = Math.round(width / 42);
                                        console.log(size);
                                        return size
                                    },
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    order: 1,
                                    hidden: true,
                                    borderWidth: 5
                                }]
                            },
                            options: {
                                tooltips: {enabled: false},
                                hover: {mode: null},
                                scales: {
                                    yAxes: [{
                                        ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        },
                                        gridLines: {
                                            color: '#eee'
                                        }
                                    }],
                                    xAxes: [{
                                        gridLines: {
                                            color: '#eee'
                                        }
                                    }]
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    position: 'bottom',
                                    labels: {
                                        padding: 20
                                    }
                                },
                                plugins: {
                                    datalabels: {
                                        align: 'top',
                                        anchor: 'start',
                                        color: 'white',
                                        // offset: 6,
                                        font: function(context) {
                                            var width = context.chart.width;
                                            var size = Math.round(width / 42);
                                            return {
                                                size: size
                                            };
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }, 1000);

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log(myChart.config.data.datasets[4].hidden);
                        myChart.config.data.datasets[4].hidden = false;
                        myChart.config.options.animation = {numbers: { duration: 0 },colors: {type: "color",duration: 1000,from: "transparent",}};
                        myChart.update();
                    }, 2500);


                } else {
                    // inView = false;  
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of chartjs do you use? v2 or v3

Comment: I'm using v2 I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it to work as intended! I went back to v2, because v3 brought too much trouble with it.

While tinkering with v3 I realized that my v2 Version worked, because Updating in v2 doesn't reset the Animation. So my answer is based on that. If you call .update(0) the update happens without the Animation. So I crated this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myChart.config.data.datasets[4].hidden = false;
    myChart.update(0);
    fadeLoop();
}, 2500);

var i = 0.15;

function fadeLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myChart.config.data.datasets[4].pointBackgroundColor = "rgba(244, 141, 59, " + i +")";
        myChart.config.data.datasets[4].borderColor = "rgba(244, 141, 59, " + i +")";
        myChart.update(0);
        i += 0.05; 
        i = Math.round(i * 100) / 100;
        if (i <= 1) fadeLoop();
    }, 10)
}
```

Since my Line Fade-in Animation was supposed to start after the Bar animation I initialized the with the hidden attribute. After 2.5 sec I removed the hidden attribute and started the FadeLoop.

I count i from 0.15 to 1 in 0.05 increments every 0.01 sec. In the Loop I Updated the BG and Border Color of my Line and Updated it "without animation".

This is not the most efficient Method, and I don't recommend it for larger Charts or slow sites. But for me this is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

For Chart.js v3 you can use the following animation options:

```js
chart.options.animation = {
  numbers: { duration: 0 },
  colors: {
    type: "color",
    duration: 1000,
    from: "transparent",
  }
}
```

For v2 I don't think they provide any fine-grain control over animations. If this is important to you, you might want to update to v3.

Snippet attached to show the effect.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['2018', '2019', '2020'],
        datasets: [{
            label: ['x'],
            data: [7.1, 6.6, 6.6],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#05368b',
                '#05368b',
                '#05368b'
            ],
            order: 2
        },{
            label: ['y'],
            data: [6.5, 6.4, 6.7],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#1792d7',
                '#1792d7',
                '#1792d7'
            ],
            order: 2
        },{
            label: ['z'],
            data: [6.1, 5.8, 6.1],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#6c2475',
                '#6c2475',
                '#6c2475'
            ],
            order: 2
        },{
            label: ['n'],
            data: [5.7, 5.8, 5.8],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#0d60b5',
                '#0d60b5',
                '#0d60b5'
            ],
            order: 2
        },{
            label: ['av'],
            data: [4.3, 6.1, 6.3],
            type: 'line',
            lineTension: 0.4,
            borderColor: "#f48d3b",
            fill: false,
            pointBackgroundColor: function() {
                var color = "rgba(244, 141, 59, 1)";
                console.log(color);
                return color;
            },
            pointRadius: function(context) {
                var width = context.chart.width;
                var size = Math.round(width / 42);
                console.log(size);
                return size
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            order: 1,
            hidden: true,
            borderWidth: 5
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
          numbers: { duration: 0 },
          colors: {
            type: "color",
            duration: 1000,
            from: "transparent",
          },
        },
        tooltips: {enabled: false},
        hover: {mode: null},
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: '#eee'
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    color: '#eee'
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
                padding: 20
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                align: 'top',
                anchor: 'start',
                color: 'white',
                // offset: 6,
                font: function(context) {
                    var width = context.chart.width;
                    var size = Math.round(width / 42);
                    return {
                        size: size
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@3.0.0-beta/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know of any hacky way to do this in v2? I just finished to write some functions to get my Chart to where I want it and I'm not sure if they'll work in v3. Also I have different other Charts on my Site and I dont want two different Versions installed.

Also, is the Upgrade vom v2 to v3 complicated or do I just have to change the cdn?
And I think you put a extra comma behind the color bracket and after "transparent"

Comment: I think the change to v3 isn’t hard. The APIs stay largely similar. Why don’t you just switch and see if anything break?

Comment: The change didn't work. v3 would break a bunch of my charts. I don't have time today to asses if its easier to fix all existing charts in v3 or just find a workaround for v2. I'll look into this tomorrow and accept your answer, if i end up switching to v3.

Comment: Hey, I got v3 to work, but it gave me some more problems. In particular updating my chart resets the animation and the Plugin Datalabels doesn't work in v3. If you can help me with this issues I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: What do you want? Fixing the broken part in v3 or a solution for v2?

Comment: I'd love a fix in v2, but as you mentioned, there isn't a easy way to fix it in v2 so a fix for v3 is fine.

Comment: Could you add a reference link? This seems to not be documented here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation

Comment: @DarkTrick if my memory serves me right, I looked into the source code to come up with the solution.